# Why are thenables that return a promise based on the same promise as the thenable not working

Tags: javascript, promise

A promise `p1` is chained with a thenable that returns a again a chained promise `p2`.
`p2` is `p1` chained with a console.log statement:

```js
    p0 = Promise.resolve();
    p1 = p0.then(() => {
      console.log("Step1");
      p2 = p1.then(() => {
        console.log("Step2");
      });
      return p2;
    });
```

I would expect the code to output "Step1" and "Step2". But it only shows "Step1". Can anybody explain, why?

I know that `then()` is usually chained like (`p0.then(...).then(...)`). So this question is not about change the code so that it runs, but about **the reason why it does not work**.

Comment: I don't see any custom thenable here, it's all normal promises

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've created promises that depend on each other in order to resolve, so neither resolve.

When you return a Promise from inside a `.then`, the Promise that that `.then` resolves to will only fulfill when the returned Promise fulfilled. So

```
p1 = p0.then(() => {
  // ...
  return p2;
});
```

means that `p1` will only resolve when:

- first, p0 resolves
- second, p2 resolves

But p2 only resolves after p1 resolves due to

```
p2 = p1.then(() => {
```

So neither resolve. Step1 gets logged because p0 resolves, but Step2 doesn't because neither p1 nor p2 resolve.